# Default or fink python and lxml under 10.6.8

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard, python, libraries

**Ah, confusion.**

I'm trying to install a python library called lxml as needed by a python script. I've been through numerous SU quesitons and answers. I haven't been able to make much progress.

I run `easy_install lxml` and get:

> Processing lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg lxml 3.0.1 is
>   already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Using
>   /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg
>   Processing dependencies for lxml Finished processing dependencies for
>   lxml

but when I run my script, I get:

> File "scraper.py", line 3, in 
>       import lxml.html   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lxml/html/**init**.py",
>   line 42, in 
>       from lxml import etree
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lxml/etree.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _htmlParseChunk   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lxml/etree.so
>
> Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/lxml-3.0.1-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg/lxml/etree.so

I think that maybe I'm not using the correct python install? I've installed python with fink, but should I use OS X's python?

This is in my .profile:

`test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh`

which points to the fink install.

`echo $PATH` gives me:

> /sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin

Should I change that to point to snow leopard's python? (Which is 2.6.1) In Library/, there is:

[image]

which are the `lxml` libaries I need, it appears, as well `as requests`.

And `whereis python` gives me `/usr/bin/python`

What do I do? How do I get python to use these libraries. And which python?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that many of the issues with lxml are because of the multiple methods to installing it, many of which are dead ends. I took a look around and found a link with instructions for installation. Take a look...

http://lxml.de/installation.html#installation